# Nginx location or map to disable access log for specific GET argument

Tags: regex, nginx, get, url-parameters, access-log

I've been trying to filter out a bunch of lines from the nginx access log. These lines contain a specific parameter, so I thought it would be easy to filter them out. Examples of the requests:

```
/index.php?cmd=thumb&#####
/index.php?cmd=preview&#####
```

where ##### can be anything. /index.php without this 'cmd' parameter (but possibly with other parameters) SHOULD be logged however.

I have tried the following

```
server {
    location ~ /index\.php\?cmd.* {
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

My guess is that location only looks at the file on the server you need, not any of the reuqest parameters. That could, for example, explain why `location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {access_log off;}` (notice the `$`) also blocks logging request like `/something.js?v=blahblah`. As such, my first option would be invalid for sure. This is confirmed [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752130/nginx-location-or-map-to-disable-access-log-for-specific-get-argument#comment57253501_34752130) (with [source](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)).

or

```
server {
    location /index.php {
        if ($arg_cmd) {
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
http {
    map $request_uri $log {
        ~ /index\.php\?cmd.* 0;
        default 1;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$log;
}
```

So far, all of the above do not have the desired result. I'm still convinced this should be possible and that I did something wrong in all of these implementations. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Your second option looks promising - but you will need to place the `if` block inside the `location` block that processes your PHP scripts. It may look something like `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thx, since I only have an index.php in this instance, the `location /index.php {` as stated above IS the `location` block where the `fastcgi_pass` etc. resides. The `if` block won't work there, however.

Comment: Very strange. I tested your `if` block and it worked perfectly. Make sure you restart `nginx` to read the new configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith After every change I quickly do a `nginx -t` and then restart the service, so I'm sure that wasn't it. I have found a solution to get the third option working, though (removing a single space). Still wondering why the first and second won't work, so leaving this question open.

Comment: My guess is that `location` only looks at the file on the server you need, not any of the reuqest parameters. That could, for example, explain why `location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {access_log off;}` (notice the `$`) also blocks logging request like `/something.js?v=blahblah`. As such, my first option would be invalid for sure.

Comment: Correct. The `location` directive tests a normalized URI - the query string (or argument list) is not considered. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details of the `location` directive.

Comment: @RichardSmith For the second option, I don't know what value you gave the paramater `cmd` when testing, but I suppose it could be the case that `if ($arg_cmd)` might not evaluate to TRUE in my case (it takes its value and doesn't give a boolean on whether it exists or not). Hence, I should have done something like `if ($args ~ cmd)` (but then every parameter that includes "cmd" would suffice, so I guess `if ($args ~ ^cmd\=) {access_log off;}` if cmd is always the first argument would do it then)?

Comment: I was using a value that evaluated true. But if you have no control over the value of `cmd` you will have to resort to your less efficient solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. First option was never going to work (see directly below it).
2. Second option will only work if the value of the argument evaluates to TRUE. I had no control over the value itself (it was a hash) in my case, so this could not work for me. In my case, another option would be `if ($args ~ ^cmd=.+) {access_log off;}` if cmd is always the first argument, or just `if ($args ~ cmd) {access_log off;}`. (thx Richard Smith)
3. I found out that the third option WILL work by removing the space between `~` and `/index\.php\?cmd.* 0;` This one allows me to globally set some more conditions to ignore, so I'm sticking with this one.